# can get_object_vars() return fields from magic __get()?

Tags: php, oop, getter

I'm running through a set of arrays and objects for further processing.
If it's an object i use `get_object_vars($obj)` to get its proberties. But if that object uses magic getters/setters, it returns an empty array. Here a little demo of the issue:

```
class Foo {
    protected
        $fields = array(
            'foo'=>1,
            'bar'=>2
        );
    function __get($key) {
        return $this->fields[$key];
    }
    function __isset($key) {
        return array_key_exists($key,$this->fields);
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
var_dump(get_object_vars($foo));
```

I want that `get_object_vars` returns the `$fields` key-value pairs. Is there any way to go, or any method to implement in `Foo` to make it work?

thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not related to magic methods, but with the fact that [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) returns an array of accessible non-static properties for the specified object relative to scope. It will return all properties if the call is from inside the objects, but, only public from outside the object. You can however, use the [IteratorAggregate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) interface, and [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) class, and combine that with [iterator_to_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) function to obtain similar behavior and some additional benefits, as in this example.

```
class Foo implements IteratorAggregate {
    protected
        $fields = array(
            'foo' => 1,
            'bar' => 2
        );

    function __get( $name ) {
        return array_key_exists( $name, $this->fields ) ? $this->fields[$name] : null;
    }

    public function __set( $name, $value )
    {
        $this->fields[$name] = $value;
    }

    function __isset( $name ) {
        return isset( $this->fields[$name] );
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator( $this->fields );
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->baz = 3;

foreach( $foo as $key => $value ) {
    echo "$key: $value ";   // OUTPUT: foo: 1 bar: 2 baz: 3
}

array_walk( ( iterator_to_array( $foo ) ), function( $value, $key ) {
    echo "$key: $value ";   // OUTPUT: foo: 1 bar: 2 baz: 3
});

print_r( iterator_to_array( $foo ) );   // OUTPUT: Array ( [foo] => 1 [bar] => 2 [baz] => 3 )
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_object_vars` only returns *visible* properties. As you're calling the function from outside the object, it has no visibility of your `protected` field, so it won't be returned.

What you can do instead is cast the object to an array:

`var_dump((array) $foo);`

This will alter the key a bit. Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) for specifics.

Another option is to create a method in the object that returns `get_object_vars` from the inside, as it will have visibility of everything. e.g.

```
class Foo {
    ...
    public function get_object_vars() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
$foo = new Foo();
var_dump($foo->get_object_vars());
```

And yet another option is obviously to simply change your property to `public` instead of `protected`.

Comment: is there way how i could tell `get_object_vars` which properties are visible? i guess not, isn't it?! Okay thanks for your answer. I'll have a look for another workaround without using `get_object_vars`

Comment: No, there's no way to give it any options. But if you use the array casting method instead, you can work out the visibility of each property by looking for the relevant null bytes in the keys.